# How to customize Look and Feel of TISwipeableTableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

according to Example suggest that i should to override drawContentView 
if i want to add some UIView in to the cell. could you show me some example please?

```
- (void)drawContentView:(CGRect)rect {
    UIColor * textColour = [UIColor blackColor];

    if (self.selected) {
        textColour = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectiongradient.png"] drawInRect:rect];
    }

    [textColour set];

    UIFont * textFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22];

    CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:textFont constrainedToSize:rect.size];
    [text drawInRect:CGRectMake((rect.size.width / 2) - (textSize.width / 2), 
                                (rect.size.height / 2) - (textSize.height / 2),
                                textSize.width, textSize.height)
            withFont:textFont];
}
```

Comment: Just add them in the setData: method or in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Make sure you remove them again, though, otherwise you'll get horrible scroll performance. I designed it with custom drawing in mind because that gives better scrolling (as outlined in a blog post by Loren Brichter).